# Make hierarchy from table with PHP

Tags: php, logic, joomla2.5, hierarchy, joomla3.0

I have a table in database and in this table i have added 3 columns that is i, name,parent_id.please see below.

```
    ID | name | parent_id

    1    name1   0
    2    name2   1
    3    name3   1
```

Now i want to fetch this id from database. I have created a method in PHP and fetch data one by one from database. Please see below

```
function getData($id)
{
            $array = array();
            $db = JFactory::getDBO();
            $sql = "SELECT * from table_name when id = ".$id;
            $db>setQuery($sql);
            $fetchAllDatas = $db->getObjectList();

            foreach ($fetchAllDatas as  $fetchAllData) 
            {
                if($fetchAllData->parent_id > 0)
                {
                    $array[$fetchAllData->parent_id] = $fetchAllData->name;
                    $this->getData($fetchAllData->parent_id);
                }
                else 
                {
                    $array[$fetchAllData->parent_id] = $fetchAllData->name;
                }   
            }
            return $array;
}
```

Now if i call this method with id 3 like

```
$this->getData(3); // has a parent
```

It will return like that

```
Array(
    [0]=>name1
)
```

But i want like below

```
Array(
    [1]=>name3,
    [0]=>name1
)
```

I know i have redefine array if we have parent but how i manage it.
i have used array_push php function but its not work with my condition.

Comment: `SELECT * from table_name when id = some_id` is this query working ???

Answer (score 1):

```
            foreach ($fetchAllDatas as  $fetchAllData) 
            {
            $array[$fetchAllData->parent_id] = $fetchAllData->name;
            if($fetchAllData->parent_id > 0)
                    array_push($array,$this->getData($fetchAllData->parent_id));                 
            }
            return $array;
```

1)Because you do `$array[$fetchAllData->parent_id] = $fetchAllData->name;` in the if and in the else, you do this in both cases so put out of `if..else`. 
2) Try to push the result of your second call in the original array to get what you want.

Answer (score -1):

you have unique ID in your table, so if you call your query it will always return only one result. Maybe you wanted to write query this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from table_name when parent_id = ".$id;
```

if you want to get the result with given ID and his parent, you should add this after calling $this->fetchSharedFolder(...);

```
$array = array_merge($array, $this->getData($fetchAllData->parent_id));
```

Comment: is it working when you change fetchSharedFolder to getData? do not forget to wrap it with array_merge as getData are returning another array as current $array is